# I am looking for a better solution to read serverside xslt and transform to xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am looking for a better solution to read serverside xslt and transform to xml.
It works fine but looking for a better soultion..thank you for your help in advance.

- XML content is passed as a string,
- Get server-side XSLT using HttpWebRequest
- Get string as output.

  ```
      string xsltUrl = "http://aaa.bbb.com/ddd/eee/JY_test.xslt";
      string outputXML = Common.Display("en", xmlText, xsltUrl);
      Label1.Text = outputXML;
  ```

---

private static XElement rawMenu;

```
    public static string Display(string lang, string xml, string xsltUrl)
    {
        rawMenu = XElement.Parse(xml); 
        return rawMenu.TransformXSLT(xsltUrl, lang); 
    }


    public string TransformXSLT(XElement results, string xsltUrl, string Lang)
    {
        //variables
        var strm = new MemoryStream();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

        //tell the stream that it will be creating a xml fragment and not a full document.            
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.CloseOutput = false;

        //pass in the lang of the page
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Lang)) //set a default just in case.
            Lang = "en";

        XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
        argsList.AddParam("CurrentLang", "", Lang);

        //// Load the style sheet.
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

        try
        {
            var stream = HttpWebRequest.Create(xsltUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            stream.Method = "GET";
            stream.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = stream.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                //Create the reader to load the stylesheet.
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(resStream))
                {
                    xslt.Load(xmlReader);
                }

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
                    xslt.Transform(results.CreateReader(), argsList, writer);
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        var strHtml = rd.ReadToEnd();
                        return strHtml;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response is HttpWebResponse)
            {
                switch (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                        throw new ApplicationException(((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription);

                    default:
                        throw ex;
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You've shown us your code, which shows that you've put effort and research into it. Now please let us know, in what way does it fail to do what you need it to? What is the result (output) of this code, and how does it differ from what you need?

Comment: @user1394089 you state in the question that it works and in your comment that it doesn't. Which is correct? Also, keep in mind that premature optimization is the cancer of software development.

Comment: It works fine..I got string result.However I think there is a better way for the after ----- using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(resStream))